# Can log in but get thrown out immediately

Tags: 14.04, boot, login

It sends me back to the login page.
I think it was after I did a software update yesterday.
I am using 14.04.
Grub2 or the BIOS has changed to boot my 2nd SSD first (I did not change this).
The issue may be down to the graphics driver (I have 2 monitors).
What steps to recover the machine?

NB. I have dual boot so I can access the files from both HDs.

Comment: Can you login into tty? Pres `ctrl +alt+f1` and login using your credetials. To go back to graphical interface press `ctrl+alt+f7`

Comment: When you get to the tty as described by Michal, run this and append the output to your question: `ls -la ~/ | head -10`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and advice. I went into the BIOS and forced it to boot the main (1st) OS and it seems to be ok now. Thanks again. I learned something anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but the computer is now booting to a different HD first. This HD had an out of date GRUB version. After running `update-grub` it is booting correctly.
NB You might need to try `sudo update-grub` depending on permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have this happen to me when I update the kernel and (for whatever reason) the nvidia driver module doesn't also get updated via dkms.

For me, the fix is re-running the Nvidia proprietary driver installer, which I usually do in rescue mode.